# Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password Credentials in this flow how to increase access token life

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

``` curl --location '``https://login.microsoftonline.com/tentId/oauth2/v2.0/token``' \ ```
`--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \`
`--data-urlencode 'client_id=xxxxxxxxx' \`
`--data-urlencode 'scope=User.Read profile openid email' \`
`--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \`
`--data-urlencode 'username=XXXXXXXXXXXX.onmicrosoft.com'\`
`--data-urlencode 'password=xxxxxxxxxxxx' \`
`--data-urlencode 'client_secret=xxxxxxxxxx' \`

Increase the life span of the access token maximum using Resource Owner Password Credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I generated **access token** using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:User.Read profile openid email
grant_type:password
username:user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com
password:***
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

To **Increase the life span of the access token maximum**, use the below PowerShell script:

```
Connect-MgGraph -TenantId TenantID -Scopes "Policy.ReadWrite.TrustFramework"

$params = @{  
Definition = @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"23:59:59"}}')  
DisplayName = "WebPolicyScenario"  
IsOrganizationDefault = $true  
}  
$tokenLifetimePolicyId=(New-MgPolicyTokenLifetimePolicy -BodyParameter $params).Id
```

[image]

The **access token lifetime increased to 24hrs** successfully like below:

[image]